# #2003 - Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, xampp, localhost

I am using xampp version 2.5.8 on windows 7. I am getting error when I try to access phpmyadmin ( `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/`).

```
#2003 - Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061) 
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
```

I am new to xampp. Somebody please help.

Comment: Well, phpmyadmin tells you that it tries to connect, but fails. Most likely either mysql is not running, or you configured phpmyadmin to look at the wrong place for it. I suggest you 1. read the documentation and 2. correct your configuration or just start mysql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have faced same problem..
open `config.inc.php` in phpmyadmin folder

change

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension']='mysqli';
```

to

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension']='mysql';
```